# How to keep carriage with XML save in VBS

Tags: xml, vbscript, formatting

I use

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
```

in my VBS to edit an XML. At the end, when I update my specific line in my XML file, I use

```
strResult = xmldoc.save(strFile)
```

The problem is, my XML file (before edit) has a carriage but after the `.save()` method the entire carriage returns disappears.

How can I keep them? It is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [preserveWhiteSpace property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761353(v=vs.85).aspx) of the document object to true.

```
xmldoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true
```

Comment: Thx you very much, this is the best way